# CSS/Wordpress: How to hide final element in a breadcrumb

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using Oxygen Builder in Wordpress, which uses a component to add a breadcrumb from Woocommerce into my product page.  When using chrome dev tools, I am not totally sure if it is possible to select the very right-most element in my breadcrumb (i.e. the product name).  Here is what the backend looks like:

[image]

Once again, I am trying to get rid of the right-most element with custom CSS in my stylesheet:
[image]

Comment: Based on the structure, it is just text inside `woocommerce-breadcrumb`. You can get rid of it using JavaScript or editing the breadcrumbs file in your themes by overriding it via child theme or hooks. Please post the code here instead of screenshot.

Comment: `woocommerce-breadcrumb {font-size:0;/* or color:transparent */}` then a reset where needed for the links about font-size or color if inherited.It won't get rid of it, but could hide it.

Comment: Instead of doing this I ended up using Yoast's (already installed) function in a code block and then I was able to select the final element and display: none;

Comment: so that was not stand alone text like shown in your screenshot ?

Comment: In the screenshot I am using a reusable component and that is what the HTML looks like.  Instead, I inserted a code block and used Yoast's PHP function to insert the breadcrumb and it had a class directly on that final element.

Comment: okay, perfect way to deal with it ;) You should make an answer yourself and select it. It will be useful to anyone else .

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by utilizing the Yoast plugin, inserting their short code, and then selecting a class they had specifically on the last element setting display: none.